# Superscript and Subscript in android

Tags: android

I want to get the superscript and subscript in textview in android. I have used the sup tag but still there is no effect.
Please tell me what's the problem since it was suggested on stackoverflow.

Comment: post your code first

Comment: <string name="exponential">X <sup><small> 2 </small></sup></string>

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, here the `R.id.text` is the ID of your textView

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>")); //for SuperScript

tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sub>2</sub>")); //for SubScript
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work for you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;

    private CoordinatorLayout mCLayout;
    private TextView mTextView;

    private String mText;
    private SpannableStringBuilder mSSBuilder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the application context
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mActivity = MainActivity.this;

        // Get the widget reference from XML layout
        mCLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        // Initialize a new String variable
        mText = "Test text to show SubscriptSpan X2 and SuperscriptSpan Y5 example.";

        // Initialize a new SpannableStringBuilder instance
        mSSBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(mText);

        // Initialize a new SubscriptSpan instance
        SubscriptSpan subscriptSpan = new SubscriptSpan();

        // Initialize a new SuperscriptSpan instance
        SuperscriptSpan superscriptSpan = new SuperscriptSpan();

        // Apply the SubscriptSpan
        mSSBuilder.setSpan(
                subscriptSpan, // Span to add
                mText.indexOf("2"), // Start of the span (inclusive)
                mText.indexOf("2") + String.valueOf("2").length(), // End of the span (exclusive)
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE // Do not extend the span when text add later
        );

        // Apply the SuperscriptSpan
        mSSBuilder.setSpan(
                superscriptSpan,
                mText.indexOf("5"),
                mText.indexOf("5") + String.valueOf("5").length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );

        // Minimize the Subscript and Superscript text size
        showSmallSizeText("2");
        showSmallSizeText("5");

        // Display the spannable text to TextView
        mTextView.setText(mSSBuilder);
    }

    // Custom method to make text size small
    protected void showSmallSizeText(String textToSmall){
        // Initialize a new RelativeSizeSpan instance
        RelativeSizeSpan relativeSizeSpan = new RelativeSizeSpan(.5f);

        // Apply the RelativeSizeSpan to display small text
        mSSBuilder.setSpan(
                relativeSizeSpan,
                mText.indexOf(textToSmall),
                mText.indexOf(textToSmall) + String.valueOf(textToSmall).length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );
    }
}
```

http://www.android--tutorials.com/2016/08/android-subscript-and-superscript.html

https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/28/quickly-add-superscript-subscript/